# Navigate through the kill ring in emacs

Tags: emacs

Consider the following situation: 
N items in the kill ring. The desired item needed to be yanked is item #k

A numerical argument solution won't really do since counting or keeping track of the position of things in the kill ring is annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the actual question? What's wrong with pressing <kbd>C-y</kbd> and then <kbd>M-y</kbd> k-times?

Comment: In general you don't know k. I should have reformulated the question by saying that your kill ring is large and the item that you want is *somewhere* in it. If you navigate via M-y fast through it you might pass the desired item thus warranting the need for a navigate backward feature.  Keeping a counter in your head on the number of times you press M-y is an unlikely thing to do in a day-to-day situation

Comment: To go back, just use `C-u -1 M-y`.

Comment: Hah! I completely forgot about negative numerical args. I guess this gets the job done. However, I simply hate the way emacs passes numerical args.

Comment: In this situation, that would be easier to type as `M-- M-y`.

Answer (score 7):

Try the `browse-kill-ring+.el` script or the other solutions [on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing).

Comment: There is also a nice article on [emacs-fu](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/04/navigating-kill-ring.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) with key <kbd>C-- C-y</kbd>, that is, a negative prefix arg to <kbd>C-y</kbd>.  That completes against the entries in the `kill-ring`, letting you choose yanks (kills) to insert.  It is a [*multi-command*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means that you can yank as many candidates, as many times as you like, with a single <kbd>C-- C-y</kbd>.

While completing against the `kill-ring` you can also clean up the ring selectively, deleting entries on the fly.  And you can [*sort*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates) the completions (the possible yanks) in various ways.  And you can type multiple patterns that the completion candidates need to match, in arbitrary match order ([*progressive completion*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion)).